# Unable to search for newline character in string

Tags: c#, string, newline, indexof

In C#, I'm looking for the index of a string inside a string - specifically the index where the newline (`\n`) character lives.

Given a string with Windows line breaks (`\r\n`):

If I look for `"\n"`, it gives me -1. If I look for `"\r\n"`, I get a result. If I look for `'\n'` as a character, I get a result.

Given a string with Unix line breaks (`\n`), I get a result.

```
string s = "hello\r\nworld";

Console.WriteLine(@"\r\n index: " + s.IndexOf("\r\n")); // 5
Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as string: " + s.IndexOf("\n")); // -1
Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as char: " + s.IndexOf('\n')); // 6


s = "hello\nworld";

Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as string: " + s.IndexOf("\n")); // 5
Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as char: " + s.IndexOf('\n')); // 5
```

I understand that line breaks are two characters, and if I was using StreamReader or File.ReadAllLines or something like that, then it would be handled automatically and I'd lose them.

I thought `\n` was a valid string by itself, and that `\r\n`, while special, still represented two separate and distinct characters in a string. But this is telling me otherwise.

I can do IndexOf on the character instead of the string (`'\n'` instead of `"\n"`), but I'd really like to know why this is happening so I can plan for it.

**EDIT**

FYI: Just found that converting the string to a `Span` gives the correct result. Not sure the overhead involved in that, so I don't know how this compares with the Ordinal solution - I'm guessing the Ordinal is the better one:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as string Ordinal: " 
    + s.IndexOf("\n", StringComparison.Ordinal)); // 6

Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as Span: "
    + s.AsSpan().IndexOf("\n".AsSpan())); // 6

Console.WriteLine(@"\n index as string with s.AsSpan(): " 
    + s.AsSpan().IndexOf("\n")); // 6
```

Comment: I ran your code and got a different result. indices by line: 5 6 6 5 5

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari Yep, that's good to know - in my case I'm trying to preserve the line breaks of the data I'm looking at, so I don't want to use the system separator in case there are some Unix-style endings in particular files - I was just trying to count the line breaks in a bunch of files when I noticed this.

Comment: @NigelBess That's really interesting - I just changed my project to .NET Core 3.1 instead of .NET 5 and it does 5 6 6 5 5 like yours - I'm guessing you ran it on 3.1? Maybe it's a framework bug (or feature that didn't get any attention). If I don't find an answer, I'll submit this to Microsoft.

Comment: @Joe Enos I ran it on .NET 6 preview 7 actually lol

Comment: @JoeEnos I just changed the project to .NET 5 and I got the same result as you. -1 for the second output

Comment: @NigelBess Awesome - they must have changed the behavior back for .NET 6 (I don't have it installed so I can't check on my machine). I see NetMage's answer and link, never knew about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a change in .Net 5.0 with the globalization libraries for Windows. In previous versions, NLS was used on Windows and ICU on Unix. .Net 5 uses ICU on both to make cross platform development consistent, at the cost of surprising Windows developers (*sigh*). Due to this change, you must pass `StringComparison.Ordinal` to find newline in a string.

Note that this can also depend on the version of Windows (double *sigh*) as Windows 10 May 2019 includes the ICU library and earlier versions that don't will cause .Net 5 to fall back to NLS.

See [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu) from Microsoft.
[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus) has more details on the APIs affected.

Comment: That's crazy - doesn't seem like that was a very good idea. I like how the article has practically the identical sample as I do. I swear I didn't steal it :)

Comment: @JoeEnos Unfortunately there are a lot of APIs affected as well. I do think it is unfortunate that a they made a globalization change that is opt-out instead of opt-in. If you don't need/want to handle globalization, you are still penalized. Perhaps they should have also changed the default for one argument `IndexOf` to be `Ordinal` and broken .Net on Unix compatiblity instead.

Comment: That's not crazy, that stupid. If I want that, I would want `StringComparison.Magic`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt `StringComparison.LetMeTellYouWhatIThinkYouWantRatherThanWhatYouToldMeToDo`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `System.Environment.NewLine` in your script, which is a conditional property for the newline character, depending on operating system. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-5.0).

On Windows: `"\r\n"`.
On unix-platforms: `"\n"`.

```
using System;
string s = "hello" + Environment.NewLine + "world";
```